# How to save a denoised image in composting

Tags: uv-image-editor, compositing-nodes, denoise, saving

### How do I save my denoised render in Blender's Composting tab?

Here's how I arrived at my problem...

1. Rendered an Image
2. Opened **Composting**
3. Added **Denoise** Node
4. Node worked perfectly
5. Attempted to save the Image
6. A soul-crushing defeat

---

### **Further Information**

I had just rendered an image and it came out noisy, I then saved the image to my computer, so that I would have the noisy image in case anything happened.

I then decided that I wanted to do what any self-respecting human being would do, and denoise the image in Blender's 'Composting' work area.

I then added the 'Denoise' node in between my rendered image and the viewer. The image then became clear, thankfully.

However, I then searched around in vain for the 'Save Image' button.

This is where I ask you, as clear as I possibly can, "**How on God's green earth do I save my now denoised image?**"

> *Why is it so hard to just make things intuitive? Can we not have nice things? I love the software, but Christ.*

[image: Dashboard in Compositing]

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to **Image Editor** ( The Paint Bucket icon )
2. Click on the Mountain Icon thingy ( See Below, far left ) and from the drop-down menu click on **Viewer Node**

[image]

3. Click on 'Image' then click **Save As** - it's near the Bucket Icon from before

[image]

4. Rejoice.